# Spring batch processor crash in between reading file and causing duplicate key exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I am currently on batch processor and the issue we are facing currently is that when Batch processor is reading files, it could restart unexpectedly in middle of reading files, this will make the full flow not working because when the BP resumes reading file it may be reading file that is already saved in database and causing duplicate key exception.

So, I have been told to implement the solution where when the BP runs into duplicate key exception, it should read the file from bottom to top and when it runs into duplicate key exception again, it should move to next file.

I am looking for advice/guidance on how to implement/code this solution?

Answer (score 0):

A correctly configured Spring Batch job (persistent job repository + chunk-oriented step) would allow you to restart that kind of failed jobs without any issue.

In fact, the read count will be saved in the database and used in a restart scenario. No data would be written to the database in case of a chunk failure (the transaction will rolled back). So upon restart, the job would resume reading from the last save point and save new data.